# how to append public keys to remote host instead of copy it

Tags: ssh, scp, key-authentication, ssh-keygen

I used in my bash script the follwing cli , in order to send the public key to remote machine

```
sshpass -p $pass scp  /root/.ssh/authorized_keys root@$remote_host:~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

but since we want to append the public keyes from other host then I am searching the approach top append

in bash I know that the option is to use ">>" but how to use the append with my approach ?

or maybe other solution ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `ssh` together with `tee -a file`:

```bsh
< /root/.ssh/authorized_keys sshpass -p "$pass" ssh root@"$remote_host" "tee -a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

or `ssh` with `cat >> file` if you prefer:

```bsh
< /root/.ssh/authorized_keys sshpass -p "$pass" ssh root@"$remote_host" "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Both `tee` and `cat` will read from stdin, which is sent to `ssh` with `< file`.
The difference is, that `tee`, unlike `>>` will print what it appends.

Note:
The double quotes are needed, otherwise the `>>` or `~` will be interpreted by your shell before sending it to `ssh` command.

Comment: not clearly how yo append the file - authorized_keys , if you only doing sshpass -p "$pass" ssh root@"$remote_host" "tee -a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"

Comment: sshpass -p "$pass" ssh root@"$remote_host" "tee -a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"  , this isnt works , still not understand from where its take the source /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: you're missing the `< /root/.ssh/authorized_keys` part, that is the source. It sends the content of the file to stdin of `ssh` command. and `tee` or `cat` reads that.

Comment: I have another little issue , I replaced the ssh with -->  /usr/bin/ssh -n -o ConnectTimeout=40 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -xaq   but this isnt works , can you advice about this?

Comment: `-n: Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin)`, so yes, as my command relies on reading from `stdin` that cannot work. But why do you want to add `-n` ?

Comment: ok I will use without -n , is it will works?

Comment: i guess it should work if you remove `-n`.

Comment: and thank you again for your great answer

Answer (score 39):

You can also use `ssh-copy-id`, which is a tool to do exactly what you want: add one or more keys to the authorized_keys of a remote system.

Comment: Usually a good idea (and should be preferred!), but in this case it won't work without additional effort as the source is another `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: @pLumo Additional effort just being that `ssh-copy-id` requires the key filename to end with `.pub`: `ln -s authorized_keys ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.pub; ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.pub $remote_host`

Comment: @JoL Is a file with several keys in it a valid `pub` file?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I tested it. It works and the manual `ssh-copy-id(1)` says (emphasis  mine) "-i identity_file Use only the **key(s)** contained in identify_file...", so acceptance of multiple keys in a single file seems intentional.